# Google sheets API in Python wrong SSL version error

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I'm getting this strange intermittent wrong SSL version error that occurs in my python server, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix it. I asked ChatGPT and it told me to update python and all my libraries, and they are up to date. The other option it gives is to force an SSL version, but I can't do that because google sheets API controls the SSL version, so what do I do? It also said I could try to do a proxy, but that feels like a janky workaround that shouldn't be necessary. Any advice would be appreciated for those who have encountered this before.

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2546)
```

Python version 3.12, Google sheets API v4.